# React router force to another page if a variable doesn't exist

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

Was wondering if react router has a way to preempt a route to check for a variable, e.g. session variable, and if that variable doesn't exist, to route to somewhere else or not at all?  This question is tied into the browser history.

My scenario is this-- when a user logs in, there are certain routes exposed.  If that user logs out, those routes are not exposed on the screen.  However, since I have browser history, a logged out user is able to see the restricted routes by pressing the back button.  Since I can not clear the browser history, I was thinking that if a restricted route gets called-- whether through router or through history--that there is a way to preempt the call and check if the user is logged in before allowing that route to proceed.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that has more to do with how your authorizing users and less to do with React Router...  There should be an auth check you have in place that checks to see if a user is authorized then conditionally render a route for that user.

Comment: using higher order components could help alot with this.  Check this article out if you would like some clarification https://hackernoon.com/role-based-authorization-in-react-c70bb7641db4

Comment: I'm actually doing your 1st comment above-- if a user is already authenticated, the app will show (render) different accessible routes.  When a user logs out, those different routes are not rendered.  The question I have is the history.  If a user logs in, goes through a few authorized-required routes, logs out, and then starts hitting the back button, I want to make sure any of those authorize-required routes can not be re-rendered or cached.  They should either redirect or not render at all.

Comment: If the route is checking for a method authentication before it renders, then it won't matter if they hit the back button.  If they aren't authenticated, the route will redirect them to a different route.  Try checking @Chase DeAnda's answer as it cover exactly what I'm describing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I handle this in my app with an `AuthenticatedRoute` component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthenticatedRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    return session.VARIABLE
        ? <Route render={ props => <Component {...props} {...rest} />} />
        : <Redirect to="/login" />;
};

export default withRouter(AuthenticatedRoute);
```

Usage:

```js
<AuthenticatedRoute path="/path" component={MyComponent} />
```

If the variable exists, it returns a normal `Route`, but if it doesn't exist it returns a `Redirect` component which will immediately redirect the user to the given path.

Comment: Interesting, but does this handle the browser history issue?  For example, say I authenticate and successfully see the page rendered by the AuthenticatedRoute.  Now that route is pushed into the browser history.  Now after going through a few authenticated (and non-authenticated) routes, I log out.  If I hit the back button and back into one of your AuthenticatedRoutes, with that AuthenticatedRoute redirect me to the /login page?

Comment: If your session variable is still set then yes, I would guess that it would still send you to the authenticated route. But, you can see that I wrap the component in the `withRouter` HOC. That means, any history change will cause this component to re-render. So, if you clear the session variable and then try to go back to the page, it should cause a re-render of the `AuthenticatedRoute` which will see that the session variable doesn't exist anymore and then it should return the `Redirect` component instead of the `Route`. Haven't tested this, but in theory it seems like thats how it should work